# В БЭМ директива @extend не нужна?

Tags: sass, бэм

Здесь описывается директива @extend которая "расширяет класс" чтобы не забыть использовать вместе с определённым классом другой класс(модификатор в БЭМ). Но модификатор в БЭМ не может использоваться без блока/элемента. Значит @extend в БЭМ не нужна? Или это может быть использование двух блоков вместе?

https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/pravila_i_direktivi/direktiva_extend/

Comment: `@extend` позволяет переиспользовать общие настройки в разных классах. К бэму это никакого отношения не имеет, его можно использовать, можно не использовать.

Comment: @Grundy а когда это можно использовать? Как reset?

Comment: не понял вопрос. Если у тебя есть какая-то часть, которую ты хочешь использовать в нескольких классах, тогда вполне подходит extend